# Moment.js to convert to correct timezone

Tags: javascript, mongodb, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to convert my date to the correct time zone with moment.js. However, I always get the whole thing without a time specification.

Here is my program code:

```
  console.log(von);
  console.log(bis);

  var nVon = moment.tz(von, "Europe/Berlin");
  var nBis = moment.tz(bis, "Europe/Berlin");

  console.log(nVon.format());
  console.log(nBis.format());
```

This is what I see in the console:

> 2022-10-31T00:00:00+01:00

And here the original German format, which I want to save in the correct time zone in MongoDb.:

[image]

The problem is that it is saved in MongoDB with an hour loss of time like this, without UTC etc.: 2022-10-31T19:44:39.000+00:00

Answer (score 0):

Date values in MongoDB are stored as UTC times - **always and only**!

If you need to preserve the client input time zone, then you must store it in a separate field. Usually the client takes responsibility to display the MongoDB UTC times as local times.

NB, you should **never** store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. Thus store

```
moment.tz(von, "Europe/Berlin").toDate()
```